# why is my lambda expression being a character?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

`a.Charge.Company.Name` is a string
and here is my lambda expression

```
var CompanyNameList = Prop.ChargeItems.SelectMany( a => a.Charge.Company.Name).ToList();
```

Yet `CompanyNameList` is a `List<char>` not `List<string>`...*why?*

Comment: Because you are using `SelectMany`. You probably just want `Select`.

Comment: @vcsjones Should put that as an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using `SelectMany`, which means project the individual items of another enumerable of enumerables. `Company.Name` I presume is a string, which is a collection of `char`s.

You probably want to just use `Select` given your expectations.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx), you need probably Select here.

> SelectMany: Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable
>   and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

So executing `SelectMany` you get `IEnumerable<char>`, after you call `ToList()`, which projects it to a `List<char>`

Comment: Could you please link English MSDN instead of Italian (I guess)?

Comment: @Win: it is in english.

Comment: It is fixed now. Thanks! +1

Comment: @Tigran your MSDN link was pointing to the `it-it` locale, so it showed as Italian.

Comment: Invoking `ToList()` on a `List<string>` doesn't result in a `List<char>`, it results in a `List<string>` and an effective no-op. By invoking `SelectMany` on a `IEnumerable<string>` you get a `IEnumerable<char>`, because `string : IEnumerable<char>`. The `ToList()` here only enumerates the `IEnumerable<char>` into a `List<char>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: yes, actually IEnumerable<char>, too much speed. going to correct..

Answer (score 3):

There were a few other answers, but I thought I'd include an explanation.

If you look at the MSDN definition of a [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx), you'll see that it is implemented as an `IEnumerable<char>`:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public sealed class String : IComparable, 
    ICloneable, IConvertible, IComparable<string>, IEnumerable<char>, 
    IEnumerable, IEquatable<string>
```

Then, compare that to the definiton of [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb534336.aspx):

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence

(there's a pretty good visual explanation here: http://www.codethinked.com/a-visual-look-at-the-linq-selectmany-operator)

Since the `SelectMany` will treat the `String` as an `IEnumerable<char>` object, 
we can infer that the resulting collection from `.SelectMany(x => x.Name)` will be an `IEnumerable<char>` made up of all of the characters contained within `Name`.

So, in this case, since you're really only looking for all of the `Name` strings contained within your `a.Charge.Company` objects, you really just need to use `Select`:

```
var CompanyNameList = Prop.ChargeItems.Select(a => a.Charge.Company.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: That was very thoughful of you, i appreciate it!